# Возникает ошибка при попытке вызова значения как функции

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте!

Скажите, пожалуйста, как можно исправить вот такую ошибку: **Uncaught TypeError: y is not a function**

```js
function test($t, y) {
 y($.trim($($t).val()));
}
function validateTest(z){
 alert(z);
}
$('.requed').on('change', function() {
  test('#'+$(this).attr('id'), 'validate'+$(this).attr('data-var'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <label for="signin-login">Логин</label>
  <input class="full-width requed" id="signin-login" data-var="Test" type="text" placeholder="Логин" name="login">
  <span class="cd-error-message"></span>
</p>
```

Я так понимаю ошибка возникает при попытке вызова значения как функции. Мне же нужно именно так. Полей у меня множество и исходя из значения (`'validate'+значение из data-var`) пришедшего из поля, будет вызываться определенная функция.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В зависимости от контекста исполняемой функции. Если все находится в контексте `window`, то можно написать так:

```js
function test($t, y) {
    var func = window[y];
    func($.trim($($t).val()));
}
function validateTest(z){
    alert(z);
}
$('.requed').on('change', function() {
  test('#'+$(this).attr('id'), 'validate'+$(this).attr('data-var'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <label for="signin-login">Логин</label>
  <input class="full-width requed" id="signin-login" data-var="Test" type="text" placeholder="Логин" name="login">
  <span class="cd-error-message"></span>
</p>
```

В ином случае нужно заменить `window` на имя объекта-предка, содержащего эту функцию

Comment: Спасибо! То, что нужно:)

Comment: @Дима, прими один из ответов нажатием на галочку слева от него. минус этого ответа в помещении функций в глобальную облась, а возможный плюс в помещении выбора функции по имени внутрь `test`. UPDATE: о, пока я писал комментарий, ты уже принял :)

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский А как Вам вариант у Qwertiy ? Может его лучше использовать?)

Comment: @Дима да, мне нравится его вариант. О недостатке, кстати, варианта с windows - он написал.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function test($t, y) {
  y($.trim($t.val()));
}

var validators = {
  Test: function validateTest(z) {
    console.log(z);
  }
}

$('.requed').on('change', function() {
  test($(this), validators[$(this).attr('data-var')]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <label for="signin-login">Логин</label>
  <input class="full-width requed" id="signin-login" data-var="Test" type="text" placeholder="Логин" name="login">
  <span class="cd-error-message"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Спасибо!:) Тоже отличный вариант!

Comment: Кстати, в Вашем варианте я так понял функция вызывается не по имени из data-var. А как быть, если 5 функций таких будет (и 5 полей с разным соответственно значением в data-var) ?

Comment: @Дима, по имени: `validators[$(this).attr('data-var')]` - берётся поле объекта `validators` с именем из атрибута `data-var`. В соседнем ответе делается примерно то же самое, но в другом месте и из глобального скоупа: `window[y]`.

Comment: Я не понял как быть со вторым полем, чтобы для него вызвать функцию, например, validateName. Куда её вставить не пойму. Вот [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/f425pwq1/4/). Возможно и Ваш вариант буду использовать:)

Comment: @Дима, `var validators = { Test: function (z) { ... }, Name: function (z) { ... } }`

Comment: Сделал, но при вводе в поле имя, в консоли показывает значение поля логин, а значение поля имя вообще не показывает. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, [код](https://jsfiddle.net/f425pwq1/5/)

Comment: @Дима, это у тебя баг в том, что id одинаковые. И вообще, нет абсолютно никакого смысла искать элемент заново, когда он уже есть - улучшил скрипт. https://jsfiddle.net/f425pwq1/6/

Comment: Точно, не внимательный Я. Спасибо!